# Compare sysdate month with a column data

Tags: oracle-10g

im application developer and we are using Oracle database for this project. I never used oracle before so i want some help to build a simple query. I have a CARD table with these columns `EXPIREMONTH` and `EXPIREDAY`. I would like to return the CARDS that will expire in the next month from the SYSDATE

```
  select * from CARDS where EXPIREMONTH == Sysdate('MM' + 1) // something like this
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not specified the data type of ExpireMonth.  If it is a date or timestamp you can try this

select * from CARDS where EXTRACT(MONTH FROM EXPIREMONTH)  + 1 = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + 1